# Undefined attribute name "isELIgnored"

Tags: jsp

`I'm trying to use Taglib to check if statement using jsp but its throwing me warning saying
" Undefined attribute name "isELIgnored" ";

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucJZz.png)
this is my code and was expecting it to return True block

Comment: Don't post images. The error message itself doesn't explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using tomcat 8 replace webapp tag content and doctype tag content with below in web.xml file , and isElegnored false on jsp page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
```